# MSSQL PHP driver returns DateTime string as NULL

Tags: php, sql-server, database, datetime

When doing an INSERT via PHP into a MSSQL DB, I get the following error:

> mssql_query(): message: Cannot insert the value NULL into column
>   'wmu_startdate', table 'wmuPortal.dbo.tbl_projects'; column does not
>   allow nulls. INSERT fails. (severity 16)

But the SQL string is

```
INSERT INTO tbl_projects
    (startdate)
VALUES
(
    (SELECT CAST('31-08-2016' as datetime))
)
```

The Query executes fine when run in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. Via the PHP Extension, the error above occurs. I already toggled `mssql.datetimeconvert = Off #/On` in php.ini.

The same error occurs without the SELECT CAST statement, ie. only a String as the value. The `startdate` column is of type datetime.

**UPDATE**

I now have a working query. But this still doesn't solve whatever causes the incorrect handling of dates by default...

Replacing the SELECT CAST Statement with

```
(SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '31-08-2016', 105))
```

Does the trick. Now: *What setting do I have to alter in order to get the mssql/freetds extension to handle this automatically?*

A known-good test server does not specify anything in `/etc/freetds/locales.conf` or other places. `mssql.datetimeconvert = Off` is set on both servers.

I also set other time/date related options in php.ini (copied from known-good server), without success. **Is datetime handling affected by other system/environment variables?**

Comment: Please, provide your PHP code.

Comment: Done. I already tested a bunch of things. I'm pretty sure it's the mssql PHP extension (not my PHP code), as other queries use the same function in the class executing the query, and SELECTs run fine. The same code runs on another machine a colleague configured. Unfortunately, it runs another Linux distribution with different apache + PHP version, so I can't simply copy all config from there.